# The method until(Function) in the type Wait is not applicable for the arguments (new Function(){})

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I got this error while compiling my code in Selenium WebDriver :

> @BeforeClass setUp java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>     The method until(Function) in the type Wait is not applicable for the
>   arguments (new Function(){})  Function cannot be resolved to a type

My code is :

```
    Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)    
            .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)    
            .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)   
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    WebElement myLoginButton = wait.until(
        new Function() {    
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {    
                return driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin"));    
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Okay so looking at the code you have it's a bit difficult to determine what you're trying to achieve. Is there more code you aren't sharing which is related to this block  `new Function() {    
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {    
                return driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin"));    
            }`

Answer (score 0):

In order to create your own function, you should provide `Function<? super WebDriver, ?>` function.

Or, create new Object `ExpectedCondtions`

Example:

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)    
            .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)    
            .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)   
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement myLoginButton = wait.until(
    new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {    

            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {    
                return driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin"));    
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some minor issues with the arguments & syntax you were using for **`FluentWait`**. Here is your working code block :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
//your code
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait(driver)    
    .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)    
    .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)   
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    WebElement myLoginButton = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() 
    {    
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) 
        {    
            return driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin"));    
        }
    });
```